# How Can I Declare File in travis config file?

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I created simple django project and i stored secret key, variable etc. in keys.json file. It gives this error when i try to build project:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keys.json'

How can i fix it.

My .travis.yml file:

```
python:
    - "3.7"
install:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

script:
    - python manage.py test
    - python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Check your working directory and the path to `keys.json` with respect to that.

Comment: Quite a trivial question, but is the keys.json file uploaded to github (or whatever you are using)?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande no because my project is public repository and this file contains secret keys (recaptcha key, django secret key etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on `travis ci` so this is probably not an ideal solution, but one way of solving this problem could be to add the file as an environmental variable.

Lets say keys.json looks like this:

```
{
"secret_key": {
    "plsd0nth4ckme"
     }
}
```

Its unix string representation of it looks like this:

```
'{\n    "secret_key": {\n        "plsdnth4ckme"\n    }\n}\n'
```

Then go to settings:
[image]

And then add this string as an environmental variable:

[image]

Now you can make the file in for instance the install step by adding

```
printf $KEYS > keys.json
```